# how to auto-populate slug field in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, slug, slugify

i want to allow users of a website create blog post from a form that i made, but the slug field does not get populated automatically from the frontend but from the backend (admin page) it does get populated, and that is not what i want. I want the slug field to get populated with the title when the users want to create a post e.g  **this-is-an-example** please how do i go about it

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog-images/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Post Thumbnail")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:blog-details", args=[self.slug])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_post(request):
    info = Announcements.objects.filter(active=True)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.creator = request.user
            form.save()  # ← no commit=False
            messages.success(request, f'Hi, Your Post have been sent for review and would be live soon!')
            return redirect('blog:home')
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'info': info,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/newpost.html', context)
```

forms.py **NOTE** *if i remove the 'slug' from the field it throws an error saying that slug is needed*

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'content', 'image', 'category')
```

newpost.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p><span style="color: black;"><b>NOTE</b></span>: For slug field, input the title as slug field but with hypens in between text <br> e.g <span style="color: black;"><b> "this-is-a-new-post"</b></span></p>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form|crispy}}
  {{form.media}}
  <div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn theme-bg rounded" type="submit">Post Content</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already has a method for slugs. You can override your save model method and add the slugify field.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```